# Dar formato a celda con PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, formato

Buenas chicos tengo un problema con PHPExcel, lo que quiero es dar formato de fecha al valor que recupero del archivo xlsx.
Me sale este error

> Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorage_Memory' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Paginas
>   prueba\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\CachedObjectStorageFactory.php on
>   line 177
>
> Warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   class 'PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorage_Memory' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Paginas
>   prueba\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\CachedObjectStorageFactory.php on
>   line 177
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isDataSet() on
>   bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\Paginas
>   prueba\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php:1148 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Paginas
>   prueba\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php(908):
>   PHPExcel_Worksheet->getCell('A1') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Paginas
>   prueba\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php(192):
>   PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->load('visitas.xlsx') #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Paginas prueba\PHPExcel\leer.php(16):
>   PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('visitas.xlsx') #3 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Paginas prueba\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Worksheet.php
>   on line 1148

Este es mi codigo:

```
    <?php

  include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
  include 'Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php';
  include 'Classes/PHPExcel/Cell/DataType.php';
  include 'Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php';
  include 'Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php';
  include 'Classes/PHPExcel/Style/NumberFormat.php';
  include 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';


    $file = 'visitas.xlsx';

    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);
  $hojaExcel = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $numRows = $hojaExcel->getHighestRow();
  $maxCol = $hojaExcel->getHighestColumn();
  $numColums = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($maxCol);

  echo '<table border=1>';
  echo "<tr>";
  for ($i=0; $i < $numColums; $i++) {
    $header = $hojaExcel->getCellByColumnAndRow($i, 1)->getValue();
    if ($i > 0) {
      $hojaExcel->getStyle('B1:'.$maxCol.'1')
                ->getNumberFormat()
                ->setFormatCode('yyyy-mmm-dd');
      $letra = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($i);
      $header = $hojaExcel->getCell($letra.'1')->getFormattedValue();
    }
    echo '<td>'.$header.'</td>';
  }
  echo "</tr>";
  for ($i=2; $i <= $numRows; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($j=0; $j < $numColums; $j++) {
      $header = $hojaExcel->getCellByColumnAndRow($j, $i)->getValue();
      echo '<td>'.$header.'</td>';
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo '</table>';
?>
```